# While loop in bash script for echoing out hexadecimal numbers

Tags: bash, while-loop, hex

I want a bash script to print list of incremental MAC addresses. This is the while loop I'm using:

```
i=1
j=1
k=1
while [ $i -le 5 ]; do
j=1
while [ $j -le 46 ]; do
k=1
while [ $k -le 44 ]; do
    echo "mac=00:00:01:$i:$j:$k"
k=`expr $k + 1`
done
j=`expr $j + 1`
done
i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

I want the MACs to print in hexadecimal. So I want this -

```
00:00:01:01:09:09
```

to increment to this -

```
00:00:01:01:09:0a
```

and NOT to this -

```
00:00:01:01:09:10
```

Comment: Use `k=$(( k + 1 ))` instead of `expr` for integer arithmetic in `bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `printf` builtin bash command, and change your `echo` with

```
  printf "mac=00:00:01:%2.2x:%2.2x:%2.2x\n" $i $j $k
```

Comment: Wouldn't `%2x` be sufficient for each octet?

Comment: Maybe not ideal, because you'll end up with spaces instead of zero padding. Alternatively you can use `%x` and have a format with single digit for number below 16.

Comment: Zero padding can be provided with `%02x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=1
j=1
k=1
# using for loop instead of while loop 
for i in $(seq 1 5); do
    j=1
    for j in $(seq 1 46); do
        k=1
        for k in $(seq 1 44); do
            echo "mac=00:00:01:$i:$j:$k"
            #using following command for HEX increment.

            k=`echo "obase=ibase=16;${k}+1"`
         done
         j=`echo "obase=ibase=16;${j}+1"`
    done
    i=`echo "obase=ibase=16;${i}+1"`
done
```

Comment: Prefer `for ((i=1; i<=5; i++)); do` to `for i in $(seq 1 5); do`. Neither is portable, but the former is much more efficient for the tagged shell `bash`.

Comment: Also, your calls to `bc` are meaningless; the output of `bc` is overwritten at the top of each loop.

Comment: @chepner, thank you sir for your insight. I have removed bc from the loop.

Comment: You fixed the wrong problem.

Comment: about the for loop , I am using sh shell where that syntax it not served well.  I am missing something ?

Comment: The OP is asking about `bash`, so the fact that you are using a shell that doesn't support this `bash` feature isn't relevant.